# When is a functional a convex combination of other functionals?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Suppose that $f, g_1,...,g_n$ are functionals defined on a normed vector space $E$ and that for each $x \in E$ we have that $f(x)$ is in the convex hull of $\{g_1(x),...,g_n(x)\}$. Does this imply that $f$ is a convex combination of $g_1,...,g_n$?

I know this is true when $E$ is reflexive, because then every functional $\phi$ on the space of functionals is in fact an evaluation for some point $x$, and the property above says that we cannot separate $f$ from the convex hull, and thus, by the Hahn-Banach theorem $f$ is a convex combination of $g_i$.

Does the property hold in non-reflexive spaces? Is there other simpler way to prove it? If the property does not hold, a counter example would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

The same proof also works in the non-reflexive case, but you have to equip $E^*$ with the weak-$*$ topology.

Let me sketch the main steps:

- We define $G \subset E^*$ to be the convex hull of all $g_i$.
- It is not hard to show that $G$ is weak-$*$ closed (using, e.g., that $G$ lives in a finite dimensional subspace of $E^*$).
- We proceed by contradiction and assume that $f \not\in G$. Then, you can apply the Hahn-Banach separation theorem in the topological space $(E^*, \tau)$, where $\tau$ is the weak-$*$ topology. Since the topological dual of $(E^*, \tau)$ is $E$, you get a point $x \in E$, such that
  $$f(x) = \langle x, f\rangle < \langle x, g_i\rangle = g_i(x),$$
  which is a contradiction to your assumption.